# How do I publicize a cool bookmarklet?

Tags: open-source, browser

I wrote a really cool bookmarklet and now I want to tell everyone.  I have absolutely no idea where to go, is there some sort of exchange for these things?

In case anyone is curious: I was tired of having to retype URLs from my desktop browser on to my phone browser, with its itsy-bitsy keyboard, so I wrote a bookmarklet that converts the current URL to a QR code, which I can scan in a few seconds.

```
javascript:window.location="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl="+escape(window.location)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A perfect place for your script would be a place like http://news.ycombinator.com/ or twitter.com

If this is useful to enough people they will retweet it and amplify the reach of it.

Comment: I submitted it to ykombinator, let's see what happens.  (Ironically, there's a ykombinator submission bookmarklet.)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to make a simple mobile website where your customers on their phones can understand what's your bookmarklet for and an easy tutorial about how to add it to the bookmarks of the browser. For example the [Tweetie client bookmarklet page](http://www.atebits.com/___?javascript%3awindow.location=%27tweetie%3a%27%20window.location) is a great starting point for you.

After You've made your site, find some way to make it more visible: Index it to Google and tweet about it, that site @kventil said about is good too.